# Avalon Dock Document Content Save Before Closing C#

Tags: c#, avalondock

I am using Avalon Dock in a project that's similar to notepad++  i have the documents as Document content, the problem that im facing is that when a user closes a document content

i want him to get a pop up msg if he/she wants to save the document before closing.

How can i accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does the dock component expose the onTabClosing event where you could set e.Cancel to true if user cancels instead of saving... for example?

Comment: @Davide Piras my class extends an Avalon Document Content and i add it to my DockingManager. 
each document has a close button I can close it but i want to prompt the user if he/she want to save before
 I dont know how to catch the closing event or how and where to call it.
` public partial class EditorCtrl : DocumentContent`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the version of AvalonDock I'm using (1.2.2668.0), I can simply define a handler for the Closing event of a DocumentContent.

example for adding a handler to a DocumentContent, I am adding a handler to the Closing event:

```
DocumentContent dc = new DocumentContent();
dc.Closing += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs>(dc_Closing);
```

The sample handler:

```
    void dc_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult Res = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save?", "Save document?", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Question);
        switch (Res)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.Cancel:
                //User cancelled, he probably doesn't want to close the window
                e.Cancel = true; 
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                //Nothing to do - continue closing
                e.Cancel = false;
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                //He does want to save - launch save here!
                Save_Function_For_DocumentContent(sender);
                e.Cancel = false;
                break;
            default:
                //Something unexpected, better abort
                e.Cancel = true; 
                break;
        }
```

Hope this helps, if not, which version of AvalonDock are you using?
        }

Comment: Do u have any idea how to disable the floating behavior of a DocumentContent in a DocumentPane ?

Comment: Normally "dc.IsFloatingAllowed = false;" should suffice unless you've done something special. (Assuming dc is a DocumentContent)

I tested it in Sample1_35 from AvalonDock 1.3 (Build 3571).

Comment: Thank you. I didnt find any good documentation for AvalonDock, you are my savior.